# how to compile or integrate my python code and Cpython code?

Tags: python, gcc, compiler-construction, cpython, pypy

1. here i have a test.py for example
   `print("hello world")`
2. I've cloned CPython source code, and I learned how to compile a python.exe
3. how to combine my source code `test.py` with the compiled executable? so that once I run the compiled executable, it will print "hello world"
4. I know how to do it with Pyinstaller or Nuitka, but I want to try it myself.

Comment: You don't have to integrate (or build) anything. Just download the interpreter (https://www.python.org/downloads), install it, and run your file.

Comment: @CristiFati what i want to do is build my own package tool